# django-admin-sortable NoReverseMatch error on get_do_sorting_url

Tags: python, django, django-admin, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use **django-admin-sortable** but once I save an object and try to load it in the Admin interface I get a **NoReverseMatch on line 43 of the adminsortable/edit_inline/tabular.html** template.

I really have no clue what I've done wrong.

I'm using `Python 2.7` and `Django 1.4`. I installed django-admin-sortable from pip.

Below is stack trace output.

> Environment:
>
> ```
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/reports/reportsuser/7/
>
> Django Version: 1.4.2
> Python Version: 2.7.3
> Installed Applications:
> ('django.contrib.auth',
>  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>  'django.contrib.sessions',
>  'django.contrib.sites',
>  'django.contrib.messages',
>  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>  'django.contrib.admin',
>  'django.contrib.admindocs',
>  'functional_tests',
>  'reports',
>  'adminsortable')
> Installed Middleware:
> ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
>
>
> Template error:
> In template /home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adminsortable/templates/adminsortable/edit_inline/tabular.html, error at line 43 Reverse for 'reports_do_sorting' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'model_type_id': 44L}' not found.
>    33 :           {% spaceless %}
>
>
>    34 :           {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
>
>
>    35 :             {% for line in fieldset %}
>
>
>    36 :               {% for field in line %}
>
>
>    37 :                 {% if field.is_hidden %} {{ field.field }} {% endif %}
>
>
>    38 :               {% endfor %}
>
>
>    39 :             {% endfor %}
>
>
>    40 :           {% endfor %}
>
>
>    41 :           {% endspaceless %}
>
>
>    42 :           {% if inline_admin_form.original %}
>
>
>    43 :           <input type="hidden" name="admin_sorting_url" value=" {% get_do_sorting_url inline_admin_form.original %} " />
>
>
>    44 :           {% endif %}
>
>
>    45 :         </td>
>
>
>    46 :         {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
>
>
>    47 :           {% for line in fieldset %}
>
>
>    48 :             {% for field in line %}
>
>
>    49 :               <td class="{{ field.field.name }}">
>
>
>    50 :               {% if field.is_readonly %}
>
>
>    51 :                   <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
>
>
>    52 :               {% else %}
>
>
>    53 :                   {{ field.field.errors.as_ul }}
>
>
> Traceback:
> File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>   136.                     response = response.render()
> File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
>   104.             self._set_content(self.rendered_content)
> File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
>   81.         content = template.render(context)
> File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>   140.             return self._render(context)
> File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
>   134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
> File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>   823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
> File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>   74.             return node.render(context)
> File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py"
> ```
>
> in render
>         123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
>         134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>         823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>         74.             return node.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
>         123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
>         134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>         823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>         74.             return node.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
>         62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>         823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>         74.             return node.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
>         62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>         823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>         74.             return node.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
>         185.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
>         166.             return self.render_template(template, context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render_template
>         137.         output = template.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>         140.             return self._render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
>         134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>         823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>         74.             return node.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
>         185.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
>         281.                 return nodelist.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>         823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
>         74.             return node.render(context)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
>         1107.                     return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adminsortable/templatetags/adminsortable_tags.py" in get_do_sorting_url
>         40.     return reverse('admin:%s_do_sorting' % obj._meta.app_label, kwargs={'model_type_id': obj.model_type_id() })
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
>         476.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
>       File "/home/josh/.virtualenvs/vvreports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
>         396.                 "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
>
> ```
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /admin/reports/reportsuser/7/
> Exception Value: Reverse for 'reports_do_sorting' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'model_type_id': 44L}' not found.
> ```

Comment: I'd guess it has something to do with `get_do_sorting_url`. That doesn't seem to be a part of `django-admin-sortable`, is it something you wrote?

Comment: It is part of django-admin-sortable, `adminsortable.templatetags.adminsortable_tags.get_do_sorting_url`

Answer (score 3):

A new version of [django-admin-sortable](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-sortable/) - 1.3.6 includes a fix for an error in the value that was being passed to the get_do_sorting_url template tag.

[EDIT]

So, after working with the original poster, it turns out this is a [known issue](https://github.com/btaylordesign/django-admin-sortable/issues/9) in django-admin-sortable: inlines can't currently be sortable within a model that doesn't inherit from sortable.